# mongodb - search on sub document and return results sorted

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Please tell me there is a way to query multiple fields in arrays (e.g. $elemMatch ) AND have a sort applied - it is being ignored if I query more than one field in l.

The documents are not returned in ts: -1 sort order - works fine if I query one array field.
The skip and limit do not affect the sort as expected.

Sample query

```
db.transactions.find({ 'l.id': '5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad', 'l.t': 'organization'  } ).sort({ ts: -1 }.skip(0).limit(10).toArray()
db.transactions.find({ l: { $elemMatch: { id: '5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad', t: 'organization' }  } } ).sort({ ts: -1 }.skip(0).limit(10).toArray()
```

This aggregate works, but I lose the rest of the contents of l

```
db.transactions.aggregate({$unwind:"$l"},{$match:{"l.t":"organization", "l.id":"5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"}}, {$sort:{"ts":-1}})
```

Sample data - ignore the duplicated ids, not a factor for this question.

```
    [
    {
            "t" : "organization.save",
            "d" : {
                    "new" : false,
                    "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
            },
            "ts" : ISODate("2013-08-20T02:21:39.955Z"),
            "l" : [
                    {
                            "t" : "organization",
                            "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
                    },
                    {
                            "t" : "account",
                            "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
                    }
            ],
            "_id" : "95c6cd5310aa485582312319f74775a4",
            "__v" : 0
    },
    {
            "t" : "organization.save",
            "d" : {
                    "new" : false,
                    "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
            },
            "ts" : ISODate("2013-08-20T02:21:43.121Z"),
            "l" : [
                    {
                            "t" : "organization",
                            "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
                    },
                    {
                            "t" : "account",
                            "id" : "5612087d70634d009dd919e5bb07fdad"
                    }
            ],
            "_id" : "d6434c3e9a1743afaa6c0961b5a69f70",
            "__v" : 0
    }
    ]
```

**Edit:** For the purposes of getting up and running I created a compound field with t + ':' + id.
This has solved my sorting issue for now but is not ideal due to data double up.

Comment: You may not need the `skip`.

Comment: Aggregates are very limited in response size, and not necessarily a good match for all queries.

Comment: The skips don't matter - in this case I am doing paging and just started at 0 for the example.